# Поясните разницу между предложениями и нужность запятой

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены, ссп

> Я поехал, когда завелся.
> Я сел в машину и поехал.

Нужна запятая в первом? Почему нужна, если второе точно такое же?

Comment: Freerade, на сайте принято благодарить участников за полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать галочкой один из ответов на свой вопрос как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сравнить два предложения: ***Я завел машину и поехал.  Я сел в машину и поехал.***

В обоих случаях по смыслу мы имеем последовательность действий, по грамматике — однородные сказуемые, по интонации — отсутствие паузы, а по знакам препинания — нет запятой в случае одиночного союза И. Вот эти предложения уж точно одинаковые.

Теперь сравним другие предложения: ***Я завел машину и поехал. Я поехал, когда завелся.***

По смыслу предложения вроде бы похожи (тоже обозначается последовательность действия), но не совсем. Даже без контекста можно предположить, что были, например, какие-то технические **проблемы** с машиной, так что поехать удалось после их устранения. Мы подчеркиваем **зависимость** первого действия от второго.

Поэтому меняется структура и грамматика: теперь первое действие считается **основным**, а второе обозначает **время** его совершения. Получаем сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с придаточным времени. Интонационно делаем подчеркнутую паузу и обозначаем ее запятой.

Так пишется **реальный текст**, то есть автор подбирает нужный ему смысл, выбирает форму и ставит знаки по правилам.

И делаем вывод: ничего не происходит просто так, без причин. Просто эти причины нужно видеть и понимать.